# This is my proof that $e^{iz} +1 - i = 0$ has no solutions

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

So

- $e^{iz} = e^{ix-y} = \frac{e^{ix}}{e^y} = \frac{\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}{e^y} = \frac{\cos(x)}{e^y} +\frac{i\sin(x)}{e^y} = -1 + i$

Then

- $\frac{1}{e^y} \cos(x) = -1$
- $\frac{1}{e^y} \sin(x) = 1$

With some basic manipulation, we get $\tan(x) = -1$ which gives us $x = \frac{3\pi}{4} + k$, for some integer $k$

Now, since $\frac{1}{e^y}$ is always positive, for $\frac{1}{e^y} \cos(x) = -1$, $\cos(x)$ has to be negative and for $\frac{1}{e^y} \sin(x) = 1$, $\sin(x)$ has to be positive BUT at $x = \frac{3\pi}{4} + k$, $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are either both positive or negative so there are no solutions.

Is this valid? I like how I answered this question but it may be wrong

Comment: $iz = \frac{\log 2}{2}  + i \frac{3\pi}{4}  .$  To find $z$  multiply both sidesby $-i \hspace{9mm}$

Comment: This is wrong. $e^{iz}$ can reach any value $e^z$ can, which is any nonzero complex number. Here we need to reach $i-1$, which is nonzero, so certainly solutions exist

Comment: How did you come to your conclusion about $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ having the same sign? If we take, for example, $x = \frac{3 \pi}{4}$, then $\sin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = -\cos x$.

Comment: There is a countably infinite set of determinations of log(i - 1) (they differ by arbitrary integer multiples of 2πi). Setting iz equal to any one of them and dividing by i will give one of countably many values of z that solve your equation.

Comment: How can $\cos x,\,\sin x$ have the same sign if $\tan x<0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does, in fact. One can use the complex logarithm and get a value for $\ln(i-1)$. Mathematica was also able to produce a nice looking value for this:
$$\ln(i-1)=\frac12\ln2+\frac{3\pi}{4}i.$$
To avoid dealing with branch cuts and multiple values, a more correct statement is actually just
$$e^{\frac12\ln2+\frac{3\pi}{4} i}.$$

Using this you can find the solution $z=\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}i$.

Comment: Right, I completely misunderstood the question. Can you also write $z$ as $z = \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi - \frac{ln(2)}{2}i$?

Answer (score 2):

This equation actually has infinitely many solutions. Indeed for any integer $n$, the number $z = -\frac{i}{2} \operatorname{ln}(2) + \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi$ is a solution.

There are two small errors in your reasoning. First, from $\operatorname{tan}(x) = -1$ you should conclude that $x = \frac{3\pi}{4} + n\pi$ for some integer $n$. Second, $\operatorname{cos}(x)$ is not positive when $x = \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi$. In fact, $\operatorname{cos} \left( \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi \right) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

It is worth mentioning that the function $f(z) = e^z$ surjects onto $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$, and hence we could say right away that the equation in your question does have at least one solution because $-1 + i \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As a preliminary remark, your formula for $x$ should be $x = (\frac{3}{4}+k)\pi$, not $\frac{3}{4}\pi + k$.

Assuming that's what you actually meant, you are still somehow visualizing the angle $x$ incorrectly. It is not true that for $x=(\frac{3}{4}+k)\pi$ the sine and cosine have the same sign. Quite the opposite is true:

- If $k$ is even then $x=(\frac{3\pi}{4}+k)\pi$ is a 2nd quadrant angle, $\cos(x)$ is negative, and $\sin(x)$ is positive.
- If $k$ is odd then $x=(\frac{3\pi}{4}+k)\pi$ is a 4th quadrant angle, $\cos(x)$ is positive, and $\sin(x)$ is negative.

Once that is all straightened out, your solution method is fine. You'll get solutions $x+iy$ of the form $x=(\frac{3}{4}+k)\pi$ for all even integers $k$, and the value of $y$ will always be the same, namely $y=-\ln(2/\sqrt{2}) = -\ln(\sqrt{2}) = -\ln(2)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nonconstructive argument showing that this result is false: if $f \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function (holomorphic on the entire complex plane), then the image of $f$ is either all of $\mathbb{C}$, the complex plane minus a point, or a singleton, i.e., any nonconstant entire function can miss at most one point in its image. This is known as [Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem). The map $f(z) = e^{iz}$ is a nonconstant entire function missing the point $0 \in \mathbb{C}$, and so it must hit the point $i-1$. This is equivalent to the equation
$$
e^{iz}+1-i=0
$$
having a solution.

In general, if $c \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, then $e^{iz} + c = 0$ has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have by $z=x+iy$

$$e^{iz} +1 - i = 0 \iff e^{iz} =-1 + i  \iff e^{ix}e^{-y} =\sqrt 2e^{i\left(\frac34\pi+2k\pi\right)}$$

that is

- $e^{-y}=\sqrt 2 \implies y=\log \frac{\sqrt 2}2$
- $x=\frac34\pi+2k\pi$

or

$$z=\frac34\pi+2k\pi+i\log \frac{\sqrt 2}2$$